# Pulse effect on event driven architecture

Tags: javascript, html, css

Event driven architecture implementation resembling pulsing with configurable softness (intense, mild, subtle), pulsing mode (inhale, exhale), pulsing frequency (plain, dense, breathe), number of pulses (including countless pulsing) along with on demand ending and observable pulse ending event.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body { 
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 100%; 
    margin: 0px; 
    padding: 0px; 
    width: 100%;
}
.centered {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.whirl { 
    background-color: lightslategray; 
    border-radius: 100%; 
    height: 150px; 
    width: 150px; 
    transition: box-shadow 1s linear;
    z-index: 2;
}
.whirl .visual { 
    border-radius: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    width: 100%; 
}
.whirl.sensitive { cursor: pointer; }
.whirl.sensitive:hover {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 5px #fff, 0px 0px 20px 5px #777;
}
.round {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: background-color 0.5s linear;
}
.center-round {}
.outer-round {}
.round.poke { background-color: #cfcfcf; }
.offing .round.poke, .offing.round.poke { background-color: lightblue; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="whirl centered" >
    <div class="visual"></div>
</div>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var Diffuser = (function() {
    return { supply: function() {
        return (function() {
            var diffusees = [];
            var oneTimeDiffusees = [];
            
            var withdraw = function (value) {

                var once = function(values) {
                    var index = values.indexOf(value);
                    if ( index > -1 ) {
                        values.splice(index, 1);
                        return true;
                    }

                    return false;
                };
                var remover = once;

                return { from: function(values) {
                                   return remover(values);
                         }
                       , entierly: function() {

                                       remover = function(values) {
                                                     var index = values.indexOf(value);
                                                     if ( index == -1 ) { return false; }
                                                     for ( var i = 0; i < values.length; i++ ) {
                                                         if ( values[i] === value ) {
                                                             values.splice(i, 1);
                                                         }
                                                     }
                                                     return true;
                                                 };

                                       return this;
                       }
                     , once: function() {

                                 remover = once;

                                 return this;
                     }};
            };
            
            return {
                diffuseTo: function(diffusee) {
                    diffusees.push(diffusee);
                    return true;
                }
                , oneTimeDiffuseTo: function(diffusee) {
                    oneTimeDiffusees.push(diffusee);
                    return true;
                }
                , withdraw: function(diffusee) {
                    return withdraw(diffusee).from(diffusees);
                }
                , withdrawOneTimeDiffusee: function(diffusee) {
                    return withdraw(diffusee).from(oneTimeDiffusees);
                }
                , diffuse: function() {
                    var diffuseFunction = function() {
                        diffusees.forEach( (diffusee) => { (function() { diffusee(); })(); });
                    };
                    var oneTimeDiffuseFunction = function() {
                        for ( var i = 0; i < oneTimeDiffusees.length; i++ ) {
                            var diffusee = oneTimeDiffusees.pop();
                            if ( !(function() { return diffusee(); })() ) {
                                oneTimeDiffusees.push(diffusee);
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    
                    setTimeout( function() { 
                        
                        diffuseFunction();
                        oneTimeDiffuseFunction();
                        
                    }, 1);
                }
            };
        })();
    } };
})();
var vainer = ( function() {
    return { supply: (purpose) => {
        var vainers = [ () => { return false; } ];
        
        if ( purpose ) { vainers.unshift( () => { vainers.shift(); return purpose(); } ); }
        
        return { shift: function() { return vainers[0](); }
               , schedule: function(toSchedule) {
                     vainers.unshift( () => { 
                         vainers.shift();
                         return toSchedule();
                     } );
                     return this;
               }
        };
    }};
})();
var inflator = function( inflateBounder, inflatable ) {

    var pumped = inflatable || void(0);
    var colorTransitionMillis = 500;
    
    var inflatedDiffuser = Diffuser.supply();
    var scheduleCleanUp = function(cleanUpAfterMillis) {
        setTimeout( () => { 
            document.querySelector(".outer-round").remove();
            inflatedDiffuser.diffuse();    
        }, cleanUpAfterMillis );
    };

    var softness = (function() {
        
        var subtle = { pokeMillis: 60, pokeAfterMillis: 50, delayMillis: 350, className: "subtle-inflating" };
        var mild = { pokeMillis: 200, pokeAfterMillis: 50, delayMillis: 500,  className: "mild-inflating" };
        var intense = { pokeMillis: 700, pokeAfterMillis: 35, delayMillis: 1000,  className: "intense-inflating" };
        var softness = mild;
        
        return { intense: function() { softness = intense; }
               , mild: function() { softness = mild; }
               , subtle: function() { softness = subtle; }
               , soften: function() { return softness; }
        };
    })();
    var poke = function(round) {
        
       round.classList.add("poke");
        
       setTimeout( () => { round.classList.remove("poke"); }
                 , softness.soften().pokeMillis);

        if ( runner.boundChecker.bounded(round) ) { return; }
        
        setTimeout( () => { poke(runner.nextElementOf(round)); }
                  , softness.soften().pokeAfterMillis );
    };
    
    var rebound = ( function() {
        var bounder = (function(value) { 
            var reboundTimes = value;
            var rebounded = reboundTimes;
            return { value: function(newReboundTimes) {
                         reboundTimes = newReboundTimes;
                         this.reset();
                     }
                   , bounded: function() { return reboundTimes > -1 && rebounded == 0; }
                   , bound: function() { rebounded--; }
                   , reset: function() { rebounded = reboundTimes; }
            }; 
        })(-1);
        
        var breatheRebounder = (function() {
            
            var shifter = ( function() {
                return { of: function(purpose) {
                    var shifts = [() => { return purpose();} ];
                    return { shift: function() { return shifts[0](); }
                           , schedule: function(toSchedule) {
                               shifts.unshift(() => { shifts.shift(); return toSchedule(); } );
                    } };
                } };
            } )();
            var shiftRunner = shifter.of(function() { runner = ( runner == inhaler ) ? exhaler : inhaler; });
            shiftRunner.schedule(() => {});
            
            var boundedDiffuser = Diffuser.supply();
            boundedDiffuser.diffuseTo( () => { setTimeout( () => { rebound.on(); }
                                     , softness.soften().delayMillis ); });
            
            var boundedDiffused = () => {
                boundedDiffuser.diffuse();
                runner.boundChecker.withdraw(boundedDiffused);
            };

            var inhaleBoundedDiffused = () => {
                runner.boundChecker.withdraw(inhaleBoundedDiffused);
                
                shiftRunner.shift();
                runner.boundChecker.boundedDiffuseTo(boundedDiffused);
                
                setTimeout( () => { poke(runner.nextElementOf(runner.boundSource())); }
                          , softness.soften().pokeAfterMillis + softness.soften().pokeMillis );
            };
            
            return {
                echo: () => {
                    shiftRunner.shift();
                    runner.boundChecker.boundedDiffuseTo(inhaleBoundedDiffused);
                    poke(runner.boundSource());
                }
            };
        })();
        
        var plainRebounder = (function() {
            var boundedDiffuser = Diffuser.supply();
            boundedDiffuser.diffuseTo( () => { rebound.on(); } );
            var boundedDiffused = () => {
                boundedDiffuser.diffuse();
                runner.boundChecker.withdraw(boundedDiffused);
            };
            return {
                echo: () => {
                    runner.boundChecker.boundedDiffuseTo( boundedDiffused );
                    poke(runner.boundSource());
                }
            };
        })();
        
        var denseRebounder = (function() {
            var boundedDiffuser = Diffuser.supply();
            boundedDiffuser.diffuseTo( () => { rebound.on(); } );
            var boundCounter = 0;
            var boundSkipDiffused = function() {
                if ( boundCounter >= 2) { 
                    boundCounter = 0;
                    boundedDiffuser.diffuse();
                    runner.boundChecker.withdraw(boundSkipDiffused);
                    return;
                }
                boundCounter++;
            };
            
            return {
                echo: function() { 

                    runner.boundChecker.boundedDiffuseTo( boundSkipDiffused );
                    
                    setTimeout( () => { poke(runner.boundSource()); }, 0 );
                    setTimeout( () => { poke(runner.boundSource()); }, softness.soften().delayMillis );
                    setTimeout( () => { poke(runner.boundSource()); }, softness.soften().delayMillis * 2 );
                        
                }
            };
        })();
        
        var rebounder = denseRebounder;
        var boundedDiffuser = Diffuser.supply();
        
        return { times: function(value) { 
                     bounder.value(value);
                     return this;
               }
               , on: function() {
                    if ( bounder.bounded() ) { bounder.reset(); boundedDiffuser.diffuse(); return; }
                    rebounder.echo();
                    bounder.bound();
               }
               , boundless: function() { bounder.value(-1); return this; }
               , boundedDiffuseTo: function(diffusee) {
                   boundedDiffuser.diffuseTo(diffusee);
                   return this;
               }
               , dense: function() { 
                   rebounder = denseRebounder;
                   return this;
               }
               , plain: function() {
                   rebounder = plainRebounder;
                   return this;
               }
               , breathe: function() {
                   rebounder = breatheRebounder;
                   return this;
               } };
    } )();
    rebound.boundedDiffuseTo( () => { scheduleCleanUp( softness.soften().pokeMillis + colorTransitionMillis ); });
    
    var createDiv = function(className) {
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.className = className;
        div.addEventListener("click", function(event) { event.stopPropagation(); });
        return div;
    };
    
    var outerBoundSource = function() { return document.querySelector(".outer-round"); };
    var innerBoundSource = function() { return document.querySelector(".center-round"); };
    var boundChecker = function( checkerFunction ) {
        var boundedDiffuser = Diffuser.supply();
        return { bounded: function(element) {
                     if ( checkerFunction(element) ) {
                         boundedDiffuser.diffuse();
                         return true;
                     }
                     return false;
                 }
               , boundedDiffuseTo: function(diffusee) { boundedDiffuser.diffuseTo(diffusee); }
               , withdraw: function(diffusee) { boundedDiffuser.withdraw(diffusee); }
        }
    };
    var outerBoundChecker = boundChecker( (element) => { return element.parentElement == null
                                                                || !element.parentElement.classList.contains("round"); } );
    var outwardlyElementSource = function(element) { return element.parentElement; };
    var innerBoundChecker = boundChecker( (element) => { return element.querySelector(".round") == null; });
    var inwardlyElementSource = function(element) { return element.querySelector(".round"); };
    var exhaler = { boundChecker: innerBoundChecker 
                  , nextElementOf: inwardlyElementSource
                  , boundSource: outerBoundSource
                  };
    var inhaler = { boundChecker: outerBoundChecker
                  , nextElementOf: outwardlyElementSource
                  , boundSource: innerBoundSource
                  };
    var runner = exhaler;
    
    
    var inflateOn = function() {
        
        var inflateBounderWidth = inflateBounder.offsetWidth;
        var inflateBounderHeight = inflateBounder.offsetHeight;
        var inflateBounderLength = ( inflateBounderWidth >= inflateBounderHeight ) 
                                   ? inflateBounderHeight
                                   : inflateBounderWidth;
        var margin = Math.floor(inflateBounderLength * 0.05);
        inflateBounderLength -= margin;
        
        var div = createDiv("centered round outer-round " + softness.soften().className);
        div.style.width = inflateBounderLength;
        div.style.height = inflateBounderLength;
        
        var inflatableHeight = pumped.offsetHeight;
        var inflatableWidth = pumped.offsetWidth;
        var inflatableLength = ( inflatableWidth >= inflatableHeight ) ? inflatableHeight : inflatableWidth;
        var inflatableInnerMargin = Math.floor( inflateBounderLength * 0.04 );
        var roundMargin = inflatableInnerMargin > 10 ? 10 : inflatableInnerMargin;
        var outerRound = div;
        
        while ( inflateBounderLength > inflatableLength ) {
            
            var innerRound = createDiv("centered round");
            innerRound.style.width = inflateBounderLength;
            innerRound.style.height = inflateBounderLength;
            
            outerRound.appendChild(innerRound);
            
            outerRound = innerRound;
            inflateBounderLength -= roundMargin;
        }
        outerRound.classList.add("center-round");
        inflateBounder.appendChild(div);

        rebound.on();
    };

    var fantesies = [];

    var returnee = {
        exhale: function() {
            fantesies.push(() => { runner = exhaler; });
            return rebounderSelector;
        }
        , inhale: function() {
            fantesies.push(() => { runner = inhaler; });
            return rebounderSelector;
        }
        , reboundTimes: function(reboundTimesValue) {
            rebound.times(reboundTimesValue);
            return this;
        }
        , boundless: function() {
            rebound.boundless();
            return this;
        }
        , softness: {
            intense: function() {
                fantesies.push(() => { softness.intense(); });
                return returnee;
            }
            , mild: function() {
                fantesies.push(() => { softness.mild(); });
                return returnee;
            }
            , subtle: function() {
                fantesies.push(() => { softness.subtle(); });
                return returnee;
            }
        }
        , on: function() {
            if ( outerBoundSource() != null ) { return false; }
            if ( !pumped ) { console.log("pump what?"); return false; }
            
            var toRun = fantesies;
            fantesies = [];
            while ( toRun.length > 0 ) { toRun.shift()(); }
            inflateOn();
            
            return true;
        }
        , inflatedDiffuseTo: function(diffusee) {
            inflatedDiffuser.diffuseTo(diffusee);
            return this;
        }
        , inflatedWithdraw: function(diffusee) {
            inflatedDiffuser.withdraw(diffusee);
            return this;
        }
        , off: function() {
            var outerBound = outerBoundSource();
            if ( outerBound == null ) { return; }
            rebound.times(0);
            outerBound.classList.add("offing");
            return this;
        }
    };
    
    var rebounderSelector = { dense: function() { fantesies.push( () => { rebound.dense(); } ); return returnee;}
                            , breathe: function() { fantesies.push( () => { rebound.breathe(); } ); return returnee; }
                            , plain: function() { fantesies.push( () => { rebound.plain(); } ); return returnee; } };
    
    return returnee;
};
(function() {

    var pulse = inflator(document.body, document.querySelector(".whirl")).exhale()
                                                                         .plain()
                                                                         .reboundTimes(1)
                                                                         .softness
                                                                         .subtle();
    var shifts = [ () => { pulse.boundless().on(); }, () => { pulse.off(); } ];
    var doSomething = function() {
        var shift = shifts.shift();
        shift();
        shifts.push(shift);
    };
    
    var delay = 500;
    var pulses = vainer.supply()
                       .schedule(() => { pulse.inflatedWithdraw(pulser).exhale().breathe().softness.mild();
                                         var whirl = document.querySelector(".whirl");
                                         whirl.addEventListener("click", doSomething);
                                         whirl.classList.add("sensitive"); })
                       .schedule(() => { setTimeout( () => { pulse.inhale().breathe().softness.intense().on(); }
                                                   , delay ); })
                       .schedule(() => { setTimeout( () => { pulse.exhale().dense().on(); }
                                                   , delay ); })
                       .schedule(() => { pulse.reboundTimes(1).inhale().plain().softness.mild().on(); });
    var pulser = () => { pulses.shift(); };
    pulse.inflatedDiffuseTo(pulser);
    setTimeout( () => { pulse.on(); }, delay );
})();
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: This work appears to be connected to the medical literature in some way. Please supply an URL or other citation, so reviewers may better understand its goals.

Comment: I come from a medical field and kinda understand what you are trying to do. However, I will not review the code as I think it is hardly readable. For starters, I would recommend you work on readability and place comments to explain your intentions. I also would recommend you look into Javascript Class programming and start an object-orientated approach instead of a logic-orientated approach. Another thing to raise readability is not to bombard functions with multiple returns. Rather use many small global functions instead of a huge block containing dozens of returns and block functions.

Comment: To further explain, within your functions you create objects. The objects in themselves are not readable as you have to do a lot of cross-referencing. Here you could use Classes and then construct the object within the constructor and then fill it with the functions within the class not the object itself.